# Hot reload not founded in new Ui in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

[image]

as per the attached image hot reload is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just run the project,then you'll got the hot reload as bellow

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ildeberto Vasconcelos. I know this way, but it very bad UX, it need more step to make hot reload

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on GitHub that can be used until the new UI supports flutter features.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6991#issuecomment-1842155741

it used the shortcut and fixed the shortcut keymap if not work with u.